# Computer does not detect Game Controller Input

Tags: games, gamepad, joystick

I have tried using PS3, PS4, and Xbox360 controllers to play games on my Ubuntu system that is running XFCE with no luck.

In every case, the controller is detected and registers as the type of controller that it actually is, but no buttons or any other form of input is detected by my machine.

I have tried calibrating them with jstest-gtk and I have tried watching for input with evtest. Neither of them have shown any activity for any controller, even though they are registered and detected properly.

Does anyone know why this might be happening? I am using Ubuntu 14.04, codename trusty.

Answer (score 0):

If `evtest` doesn't reports anything, I assume the events are eaten by something, the xorg joystick driver might be responsible, try removing it and reboot and see if that helps:

```
apt-get remove xserver-xorg-input-joystick.*
```